# How to pass edit text values to integer array in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm a beginner in Android.

I have created a edit text field where can I enter values from 0-9. Now, I have to get these values in an integer array.

```
example : entered values are 12345.
I need an array containing these values
    int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

I need to know the way to do this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
String str = edittext.getText.toString();
int length = str.length();

int[] arr = new int[length];

for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    arr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: thanks.. that worked. and if i try to add this array to a text view I'm getting the output as '[1@313d3b04'

Comment: how you want to add the array to textview

Comment: if you want to set integer array indexes to textview as text then you have to convert integer value to string first

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
 int[] array = new int[yourString.length()];

 for (int i = 0; i < yourString.length(); i++){
     array[i] = Character.getNumericValue(yourString.charAt(i));        
 }
```

Comment: thanks.. that worked. and if i try to add this array to a text view I'm getting the output as '[1@313d3b04'

Comment: You're not suppose to add an array of ints to a TextView